# Rails cache read_multi using array of keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

I am currently trying to get my key value pair out of redis using this function:

```
Rails.cache.read_multi("asdf:1", "asdf:2")
```

It works smoothly in the example above, but when I try to get it working with an array of values it returns nil.

```
keys = ids.map {|id| "asdf:#{id}"}
Rails.cache.read_multi(keys)
```

Anyone has an idea how I get this working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Splat the keys:

```rb
Rails.cache.read_multi(*keys)
```